# Sending emails with Swift using Mailgun

Tags: swift, mailgun

```
 func test() {
        let session = URLSession.shared
        var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/sandbox(Personal info).mailgun.org/messages")!)
        request.httpMethod = "POST"
        let data = "from: Excited User <(Personal info)>&to: [bar@example.com,(Personal info)]&subject:Hello&text:Testinggsome Mailgun awesomness!"
        request.httpBody = data.data(using: .ascii)
        request.setValue("key-(Personal info)", forHTTPHeaderField: "api")
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
            }
            if let response = response {
                print("url = \(response.url!)")
                print("response = \(response)")
                let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
                print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
            }


        })
        task.resume()
    }
```

Currently running with the above code and I am getting a 401 error. I have confirmed that the credentials are correct. Any suggestions?

Comment: Find out what the 401 error means.  Your `httpBody` doesn't look right though I don't know a guy named MailGun.

Comment: Error 401 means "Unauthorized - No valid API key provided"

Comment: You should now know what to do if you know what that error code means.

Answer (score 0):

TRY

```
func email() {
    let session = URLSession.shared
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: NSURL(string: "https://api.mailgun.net/v3/{edited_out}/messages")! as URL)

    request.httpMethod = "POST"
    let credentials = "api:key-{omitted}"
    request.setValue("Basic \(credentials.toBase64())", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")

    let data = "from: Swift Email <(test@test.com)>&to: [my_email_address@gmail.com,(my_email_address@gmail.com)]&subject:Hello&text:Testing_some_Mailgun_awesomness"
    request.httpBody = data.data(using: String.Encoding.ascii)

    let task = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        if let error = error {
            print(error)
        }
        if let response = response {
            print("url = \(response.url!)")
            print("response = \(response)")
            let httpResponse = response as! HTTPURLResponse
            print("response code = \(httpResponse.statusCode)")
        }
    })
    task.resume()
}


extension String {

    func fromBase64() -> String? {
        guard let data = Data(base64Encoded: self) else {
            return nil
        }

        return String(data: data, encoding: .utf8)
    }

    func toBase64() -> String {
        return Data(self.utf8).base64EncodedString()
    }
}
```